# SQL Server - Giving Access to an SP to an AD user

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

Using SQLServer 2008 R2 and converting excel macros (vba) from SQL authentication to AD authentication. I have an AD Group called Company\Excel_Commission and and harry is a member of that group.

I can't even connect to SQL server in SSMS when logged in as CompanyA\Harry and using SQL authentication.

I added a new user CompanyA\Excel_Commission under Logins. 
Server Role is public

if I do "script user as create to" I get:

```
CREATE LOGIN [CompanyA\Excel_Commission] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Commission], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
```

I also added the user to the DB where the SP is and granted execute permission. The user is also a member of the roles db_datareader and db_datawriter in this DB:

Again if I run "script user as create to", I get

```
CREATE USER [Excel_Commission] FOR LOGIN [CompanyA\Excel_Commission]
```

Further info.

Ran this

```
SELECT endpnt.name,
       suser_name(perms.grantee_principal_id) as grantee_principal,
       perms.permission_name, perms.state_desc
    FROM
       sys.server_permissions perms,
       sys.endpoints endpnt
    WHERE
       perms.class = 105
       AND perms.major_id = endpnt.endpoint_id
```

Got this

```
name    grantee_principal   permission_name state_desc
TSQL Local Machine  public  CONNECT GRANT
TSQL Named Pipes    public  CONNECT GRANT
TSQL Default TCP    public  CONNECT GRANT
TSQL Default VIA    public  CONNECT GRANT
```

Error is Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.

Which seems to be "Valid login but server access failure"

What am i missing?

Regards

mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to SQL Server is a two step dance.

Step One is the creation of a login (which can be a Windows user/group) which users Windows passwords among other things or a SQL Server Login in which you create a user name and password (and has to be enabled). You typically assign a default database (should not be master) to the new login.

Step 2 is you use the login created in step one to create a user in one, or more, databases and grant permissions to the user to do things. Sometimes by putting the user into a SQL Server group you can grant automatic permission to that user. Try to grant as narrow permissions as possible.

Comment: Thanks benjamin. I did try setting the default database to "commission" and the user is in this DB and the user is a member of db_datareader and db_datawriter in this DB. Even tried adding membership to db_owner in this DB, but still can't even connect to SQL server with SSMS using Windows Authentication when logged in as that user

Comment: Does the user have a login on this instance? You may try to turn on auditing for failed logins so you can see what exactly is going on. Its easy and here are step by step directions on how to do it: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1735/auditing-failed-logins-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11. State 11 is "Valid login but server access failure". Found a bunch of results on google for that, but nothing that makes sense. I ran one sql command I found got:
grantee_principal permission_name state_desc
TSQL Local Machine public CONNECT GRANT
TSQL Named Pipes public CONNECT GRANT
TSQL Default TCP public CONNECT GRANT
TSQL Default VIA public CONNECT GRANT

Comment: added more detail about troubleshooting to the main post, as it's easier to read

Comment: Hi Ben. Not sure I fully understand: Does the user have a login on this instance? . We added the AD group as a login in this instance if that's what you mean. The AD group is a DomainA. The user is in DomainB, but is a member of the the DomainA group and there is a trust relationship between domains.

Comment: I have never tried adding groups from different domains using trust relationships. You may try dropping the group from sql server logins and then readding the group. You will have to restablish all the permissions and group ownership of objects to the login when you do this but it may be that the SIDS are out of sync.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Ben. Spoke to one of my IT buddies and he say it's not doable. Strange thing is if I give a fileshare permissions for that AD group it works, so the AD part is working. Given you upvote and answer checkmark for all the help